# Quick way to add user access to all databases

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have a database Server with 10 databases. One of the users is with only access to 1 database.

I would like to add this user with all the permissions that they already have to all other databases. Is there anyway where I can do it?
Or do I need to create the same user for each database?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2018.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS go to securities (under database) -> logins
Then select your user and with mouse right click select properties. Then in new window select user mapping tab. Here you select all the databases you want them to give access to. (Here you can also set roles for them). Click OK and you are done. Now they have access to all the databases.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this quickly by editing the user under Securities and under the Securables, setting permissions there.